# Cassandra 2.2.11 add new map column from text column

Tags: cassandra, alter, cqlsh

Let's say I have table with 2 columns
`primary key`: id - type `varchar`
and `non-primary-key`: data - type `text`

Data column consist only of `json` values for example like:

```
{
"name":"John",
"age":30
}
```

I know that i can not alter this column to `map` type but maybe i can add new `map` column with values from `data` column or maybe you have some other idea?

What can i do about it ? I want to get `map` column in this table with values from `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to make use of the CQL [COPY](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCopy.html) command to export all your data to a CSV file.

Then alter your table and create a new column of type `map`.

Convert the exported data to another file containing `UPDATE` statements where you only update the newly created column with values converted from JSON to a `map`. For conversion use a tool or language of your choice (be it bash, python, perl or whatever).

BTW be aware, that with `map` you specify what data type is your map's key and what data type is your map's value. So you will most probably be limited to use strings only if you want to be generic, i.e. a `map<text, text>`. Consider whether this is appropriate for your use case.